# How markup with schema.org a legal document (law, penal or civic code etc)?

Tags: schema.org

How markup with schema.org legal documents, such as conventions, laws, penal or civic codes, decrees, resolutions adopted by governmental bodies or contracts, agreements signed by organizations?

I've tried to use

```
div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"
```

or NewsArticle, but these schemas do not have all the properties needed for legal documents.

I've designed a schema for legal documents using "http://schema.org/CreativeWork"

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <itemprop="Name"> title of the act
  <itemprop="keywords">
  <itemprop="dateCreated">
  <itemprop="datePublished">
  <itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GovernmentOrganization">
    <itemprop="Name"> name of organization
```

But I didn't find any properties for document's body markup, as articleBody is in Article schema.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The closest Schema.org type I can think of is [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork).
I don’t think that `Article` is appropriate for all the examples you mentioned, but probably for some.

Related types are [`Permit`](http://schema.org/Permit)/[`GovernmentPermit`](http://schema.org/GovernmentPermit), but they are about the actual permit, not the document about/containing it.

Currently there doesn’t seem to be a related [Schema.org proposal](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/SchemaDotOrgProposals).
You can suggest new types/properties on the [mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/) or the [issue tracker](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues).